# BeautifulSoup Iterating through pages but data scraped is duplicating every loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import time

headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"}

symbol = []
name = []
asset_class = []

pages = np.arange(1, 5)
list=[]

for page in pages:

    print("https://etfdb.com/screener/#page=" + str(page))  # to watch progress
    page = requests.get("https://etfdb.com/screener/#page=" + str(page),
                        headers=headers)
    time.sleep(3) #in seconds
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')  # Parse the HTML as a string

    table = soup.find('table', class_ = "table table-bordered table-hover table-striped mm-mobile-table")

    for etf in table.find_all('tbody'):
        rows = etf.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            Cell = row.get_text().rstrip()
            Cell = Cell.replace("\n\n\n", "\n").replace("\n\n", "\n")
            list.append(Cell.splitlines())

df = DataFrame(list, columns=['Empty','Symbol', 'ETF Name',
                        "Previous Closing Price","Total Assets ($MM)",
                        "Avg. Daily Share Volume (3mo)","YTD Price Change","Asset Class"])
del df['Empty']
print(df)
df.to_csv('etfs.csv')'''
```

I added a sleep timer between pages, but that didn't help. Data is flowing in from all the pages but it is just repeating on every page. I made sure that the page numbers are working correctly in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded from external source via Javascript. You can use this example how to load the data:

```
import json
import requests


params = {"page": 1, "only": ["meta", "data"]}
url = "https://etfdb.com/api/screener/"
page = 1

while True:
    print("Getting page {}...".format(page))
    params["page"] = page
    data = requests.post(url, json=params).json()
    # uncomment to see all data:
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

    if not data["data"]:
        break

    # print some data:
    for d in data["data"]:
        print("{:<60} {}".format(d["mobile_title"], d["price"]))

    page += 1
```

Prints:

```
Getting page 1...
SPY - SPDR S&P 500 ETF                                       $408.52
IVV - iShares Core S&P 500 ETF                               $410.01
VTI - Vanguard Total Stock Market ETF                        $212.85
VOO - Vanguard S&P 500 ETF                                   $375.55
QQQ - Invesco QQQ                                            $335.08
VEA - Vanguard FTSE Developed Markets ETF                    $50.44
IEFA - iShares Core MSCI EAFE ETF                            $74.02
AGG - iShares Core U.S. Aggregate Bond ETF                   $114.31
IEMG - iShares Core MSCI Emerging Markets ETF                $65.30
VWO - Vanguard FTSE Emerging Markets ETF                     $52.65
VTV - Vanguard Value ETF                                     $132.85
VUG - Vanguard Growth ETF                                    $270.14
BND - Vanguard Total Bond Market ETF                         $85.06
IJR - iShares Core S&P Small-Cap ETF                         $109.39
IWM - iShares Russell 2000 ETF                               $222.56
IWF - iShares Russell 1000 Growth ETF                        $254.60
IJH - iShares Core S&P Mid-Cap ETF                           $265.11
GLD - SPDR Gold Trust                                        $164.51
VIG - Vanguard Dividend Appreciation ETF                     $149.85
EFA - iShares MSCI EAFE ETF                                  $77.75
IWD - iShares Russell 1000 Value ETF                         $154.08
VO - Vanguard Mid-Cap Index ETF                              $226.92
VB - Vanguard Small Cap ETF                                  $217.44
VXUS - Vanguard Total International Stock ETF                $64.13
VGT - Vanguard Information Technology ETF                    $378.80
Getting page 2...
VCIT - Vanguard Intermediate-Term Corporate Bond ETF         $93.55
BNDX - Vanguard Total International Bond ETF                 $57.28
XLK - Technology Select Sector SPDR Fund                     $140.42
LQD - iShares iBoxx $ Investment Grade Corporate Bond ETF    $131.06
ONEQ - Fidelity NASDAQ Composite Index Track                 $53.72
XLF - Financial Select Sector SPDR Fund                      $34.85

...and so on.
```